# How to display an input box on selection of options value?

Tags: reactjs, antd

In an antd React project, I've dropdown list with certain values. My intention is to toggle a textbox on selecting specific option. Consider following code example

```
import { Input } from 'antd';

const { Option } = Select;
const { TextArea } = Input;

// const [inputBox, setInputBox] = useState(false)

function onChange(value) {
  {/* if(value == "Lucy") {
    setInputBox(true)
} */}
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select
    showSearch
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    placeholder="Select a person"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    onChange={onChange}
    filterOption={(input, option) =>
      option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    }
  >
    <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
    <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
    <Option value="tom">Tom</Option>
  </Select>,

  {/* Here I need to create a TextBox on selecting 'lucy', and dismissed on selection of other option */}
  {
   inputBox ? (<TextArea placeholder="Lucy Text" rows={3} />)
  }
  
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Here is the Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/select-with-search-field-antd-4-17-0-alpha-0-forked-9qeq9

I'am unable to create that input box. Any appropriate solution highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, there's two problems though:

- You need to move your code into a component in order to be able to manage the state using `useState` hook. Then pass the component into the `ReactDOM.render` method.
- Second of all, in the `onChange` method, you need to set the variable to `false` then the input is not needed:

```
function onChange(value) {
  if(value == "Lucy") {
    setInputBox(true)
  } else {
    setInputBox(false)
  } 
}
```

or

```
function onChange(value) {
  setInputBox(value == "Lucy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`hook` can only be defined inside a functional component so you might need to do this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Select } from "antd";
import TextArea from "antd/lib/input/TextArea";

const { Option } = Select;

const App = () => {
  const [inputBox, setInputBox] = useState(false);

  function onChange(value) {
    if (value === "lucy") {
      setInputBox(true);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        showSearch
        style={{ width: 200 }}
        placeholder="Select a person"
        optionFilterProp="children"
        onChange={onChange}
        filterOption={(input, option) =>
          option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
        }
      >
        <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
        <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
        <Option value="tom">Tom</Option>
      </Select>
      {inputBox ? <TextArea placeholder="Lucy Text" rows={3} /> : null}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```